# Change layout from Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Coroutine launching

```
GlobalScope.launch(){
    get_message_pulling()
}
```

I need to edit the layout from `get_message_pulling()`, but getting the error

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: Use of `GlobalScope` is discouraged - https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by

```
private fun get_message_pulling() {

runOnUiThread {
 // ui changing code
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because using `GlobalScope.launch()` without specifying the coroutine context will run your code on a background thread using `Dispatchers.Default`, not the MainThread, you can only communicate with UI through the MainThread coroutine's context

```
GlobalScope.launch(){
   get_message_pulling()

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
       // then update the UI 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android specific `Dispatchers.Main` for performing UI updates. Also, avoid the use of `GlobalScope` for launching coroutines as explained [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/). Instead, opt for `Dispatchers.Default` or `Dispatchers.IO`.

```
// CPU bound - Dispatchers.Default
// IO bound - Dispatchers.IO
val defaultScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

defaultScope.launch {
    get_message_pulling()
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
        // Your UI updates
    }
}
```